# How could I shorten the statement in capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have to put `cd #{deploy_to}/current` and `raise_on_non_zero_exit: false` in many tasks. It smells bad.

Are there any built-in functions that can let me shorten my statements?

## Foreman config

```
  namespace :foreman do
    task :export do
      on roles(:web) do |host|
        execute %Q( cd #{deploy_to}/current && sudo foreman export upstart /etc/init -a #{ENV['APP_NAME']}  -u #{ENV['DEPLOYER']} -l /var/#{ENV['APP_NAME']}/log )
      end
    end
    task :start do
      on roles(:web) do |host|
        execute "cd #{deploy_to}/current && sudo start #{ENV['APP_NAME']} ", raise_on_non_zero_exit: false
      end
    end
    task :stop do
      on roles(:web) do |host|
        execute "cd #{deploy_to}/current && sudo stop #{ENV['APP_NAME']} ", raise_on_non_zero_exit: false
      end
    end
  end # foreman
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capistranos 'within' helper to tidy this a little, as well as wrapping the raise in your own helper method?

```
within current_path do
    execute_without_fail "..."
end

def execute_without_fail cmd
    execute cmd, raise_on_non_zero_exit: false
end
```